# Join function in Python

Tags: python

I am writing code that reverses a string e.g. GOOD ---> DOOG w/o using the reverse() function. I'm almost there...

```
a = "hello"

for i in range(1,len(a)+1): 

    print a[-i],
```

When I complete the code with the join function, it doesn't work as I expect. Any ideas why? Driving me nuts.

```
a = "hello"

for i in range(1,len(a)+1): 

    print ""join.a([-i],)
```

Comment: why not simply run the loop in reverse? `for i in len(a) .. 1` type of thing?

Comment: You do mean the `reversed` function right? (`reverse` is on list objects for instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse a string in one line like this:

```
a[::-1]
```

Slicing works like `[start:stop:step]`. So when you use -1 as the `step`, it prints the string in reverse.

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> a[::-1]
'olleh'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
''.join(a[-i] for i in range(1,len(a)+1))
```

You're passing an iterable object with only 1 item to `join` when `join` really works best if the iterable item has multiple items to actually join together.  Here I pass a generator expression.

But really, the easiest, most efficient way to reverse a string is:

```
a[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for `s[::-1]` but still, if I had to write a loop, then:

```
for i in range(len(s) - 1, -1, -1):
    print s[i]
```